# NLTK - explanation of inconsistent behavior of disperson_plot

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, nltk-book

Why `ahab` and `Ahab` make the difference in nltk dispersion_plot?

```
from nltk.book import (
    text1 as mobydick
)
mobydick.dispersion_plot(['starbuck', 'captain', 'ahab'])
```

[image]

```
mobydick.dispersion_plot(['starbuck', 'captain', 'Ahab'])
```

[image]

### Environment

```
NLTK: 3.8.1
Python: 3.9.13
```